# Access RouteMatch-Object in ViewHelper

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework2, view-helpers

In my Project, i created a ViewHelper, to display a form on every Page. If the user submit the form the Post information always posted to the same controller. After the Controller handles the post, the user should redirected to the page, where he submitted the form.

To redirect the dynamically i want to submit the controller and action via hidden elements. But i have no clue, how i can set them in the ViewHelper. I tried it with the `InjectApplicationEventInterface`, but my member variable was empty, so i guess its only work for controllers and not for helper.

So how can i access the RouteMatch Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Zend\View\HelperPluginManager`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.1/library/Zend/View/HelperPluginManager.php) is the service locator that keeps your view helpers, and it contains no instance of the application event initializer, but it has a reference to the main service locator, since it is a plugin manager. Consider implementing following in your helper:

```
public function __construct(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $mvcEvent)
{
    // injecting the mvc event, since $mvcEvent->getRouteMatch() may be null
    $this->mvcEvent = $mvcEvent;
}
```

Then, in your module's `getViewHelperConfig` (implementation of [`ViewHelperProviderInterface`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.1/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Feature/ViewHelperProviderInterface.php)) you define following:

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'myHelper' => function (\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager $pm) {
                 $application = $pm->getServiceLocator()->get('Application');

                 return new MyViewHelper($application->getMvcEvent());
            },
        ),
    );
}
```